# Is compling Views in ASP.NET MVC good practice?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, compilation

In ASP.NET MVC, you can enable compilation of views by setting following key in your project file to true:

```
<MvcBuildViews>true</MvcBuildViews>
```

Then whenever you compile your solution, your views will be compiled as well, which is great, as it allows you to find errors at compile time rather than run-time. This is particularly useful when refactoring, as it is possible to miss renamed property, or changed namespace in a view.

I can see only benefits, so why this options is not only set by default, but not even available in Visual Studio 2010 UI, and often requiring some additional changes to your config, as mentioned here:
http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2011/02/16/notes-on-building-razor-views.aspx

Are there any reasonable drawbacks to compiling ASP.NET MVC views?

Comment: Better solution to refactoring: acquire ReSharper which can *very quickly* pay for itself. Also, don't confuse "development environment" with "deployment environment".

Comment: ReSharper is a great tool, but It does not guarantee error-free views. Also, can you elaborate on confusing "development environment" and "deployment environment"?

Comment: "The better solution to *refactoring* .."; in any case, finding these sorts of issues is part of development/testing in which case fast turn cycles are very beneficial (although integration testing should stress the view compilation process, even if a bit longer of a cycle than "build"). However, this is a separate issue from an actual deployment configuration: that is, there are at least two different contexts to this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't say it's "good practice", nor is it "bad practice".  It's just another tool in your toolbox.

The reason it's not enabled by default is because, while small projects are ok.. it quickly becomes extremely slow, taking several minutes on medium to larger projects.

Also, it only catches specific kinds of errors.  So don't rely on it for everything.

Answer (score 1):

Assume this is similar to precompiling pages in a web forms project.  Yes there would be much benefit to that as it would make the application perform better, since the view wouldn't have to be compiled when the user accesses the view.

This can make smaller changes much harder though; I've run into scenarios where you have to make a small change to the code.  If you had to redeploy, it could recycle the application and force users to lose work.  I'll be honest, most of my using this type of feature was with web forms, but the process should be similar.

It also made deployments a little harder, but I don't really count that as a con since deployments are infrequent.

Comment: Yes, good point about changes to view after deployment. I never do that, so that completely fell off radar for me. I thought that setting MvcBuildViews will only compile them when you build the solution, but would not affect deployment in any way - I'll have to verify that.